# Extract Data from Transfermarkt to Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a method to Extract Data from Tranfermarkt.com website, I want to extract stats for any specific player. I tried with

> =IMPORTHTML("https://www.transfermarkt.com/zlatan-ibrahimovic/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3455", "Table", 1)

but couldn't find it working in subject website.
Anyone know any method to achieve it?

Comment: Hi there! Please detail how you used that formula and the results that you got. Also please explain what kind of results you want instead. Feel free to show an example.

Comment: Okay, let say, I want to get the table from 'Compact' to until down at 'Total' from this link https://www.transfermarkt.com/zlatan-ibrahimovic/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3455 and I am using google sheet formula '=IMPORTHTML("https://www.transfermarkt.com/zlatan-ibrahimovic/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3455", "Table", 1)' but unable to get result from this url.

Answer (score 0):

By reading your question update I understand that you want to scrape the table under the `Compact` tab (see [example](https://www.transfermarkt.com/zlatan-ibrahimovic/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3455)). Unfortunately that isn't possible. Using any other scraping method, like [`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) will return the same error (`Resource at URL not found`), implying that this particular webpage has blocked scrapping. You can workaround such circumstances by either looking for a different webpage or modifying your project.